# Json.NET how to override serialization for a type that defines a custom JsonConverter via an attribute?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a class using Json.NET and a custom JsonConverter object. The class currently defines a converter for default serialization using the JsonConverterAttribute. I need to do a custom deserialization by passing in a custom converter. However, the deserialization still seems to be using the default converter. How can I get Json.NET to prefer my custom converter?

Here's a bit of sample code that demonstrates the issue. I'm using NewtonSoft.Json 4.5.11:

```
void Main()
{
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{}"); // throws "in the default converter"
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new CustomConverter() } };
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{}", settings); // still throws "in the default converter" :-/
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(DefaultConverter))]
public class Foo {
}

public class DefaultConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception("in the default converter!");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception("in the default converter!");
    }
}

public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception("in the custom converter!");
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new Exception("in the custom converter!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use custom contract resolver. Default contract resolver uses converters from settings only if converter is not specified for the type.

```
class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter (Type objectType)
    {
        if (typeof(Foo).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
            return null; // pretend converter is not specified
        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{}", new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver(),
    Converters = new[] { new CustomConverter() },
});
```

Comment: DefaultContractResolver has changed significantly since this post so this solution no longer works.